# Mockable spring dependency injection into mapper definition

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, mocking, mapstruct

I need to access a Spring bean from a custom mapping method. But I also need to be able to inject a mock of that Spring bean when unit-testing that mapping method.

Here is a minimal example of my mapper class:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class MyMapper {
    private final MyBean myBean;
    
    public MyMapper(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }

    @BeforeMapping
    protected MyElement initElement(MyElementDto dto) {
        // custom logic using the injected MyBean to initialize MyElement
    }
    
    public abstract MyElement map(MyElementDto dto);
}
```

I would expect MapStruct to generate an implementation where it uses `MyMapper`'s parameterized constructor like so:

```java
@Component
public class MyMapperImpl extends MyMapper {
    @Autowired
    public MyMapperImpl(MyBean myBean) {
        super(myBean);
    }

    // ... mapping function implementation ...
}
```

However, MapStruct seems to ignore parameterized constructors and only support default parameter-less constructors.

So the question is: **How can I implement this type of logic in the cleanest way so that the generated mapper implementation is unit-testable and it is possible to mock the `MyBean` dependency properly?**

Using MapStruct 1.3.0.Final, Spring 4.3.25.Release, Mockito 1.9.5 and Junit 4.12.

Comment: This question suggests another way to inject the bean, maybe it helps  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807415/mapstruct-how-can-i-inject-a-spring-dependency-in-the-generated-mapper-class

Comment: @marc I am sure there must be a non-expression solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Found a solution for this case, by using `@ObjectFactory` instead of `@BeforeMapping` for element initialization. This also results in better code structure, separation of concerns and testability.

The element initialization logic would be defined in a separate Spring bean:

```java
@Component
public class MyFactory {
    private final MyBean myBean;

    @Autowired
    public MyFactory(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }

    @ObjectFactory
    public MyElement initialize(MyElementDto dto) {
        // custom logic using the injected MyBean to initialize MyElement
    }
}
```

The above component can be tested separately, mocking and injecting `MyBean`.

Then, `MyMapper` code becomes quite short, with no custom logic inside. Even `interface` can be used instead of `abstract class` (although both would work equally well):

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        uses = MyFactory.class,
        injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public interface MyMapper {
    MyElement map(MyElementDto dto);
}
```

### Generated Code

The generated implementation looks like the following. First, the factory method is called to initialize the target object, then the field mappings take place on the target object returned by the factory method:

```java
/** THIS IS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED CODE **/
@Component
public class MyMapperImpl implements MyMapper {
    private final MyFactory myFactory;

    @Autowired
    public MyMapperImpl(MyFactory myFactory) {
        this.myFactory = myFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public MyElement map(MyElementDto dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        MyElement myElement = myFactory.initialize( dto ); // <-- FACTORY USED HERE

        // ... field mapping code here, after initialization ...

        return myElement;
    }
}
```

### Unit Tests

The mapper is easily unit-testable, by mocking and injecting `MyFactory`. I wanted to avoid loading any Spring context, so I initialized the `MyFactoryImpl` instance manually.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyMapperTest {
    @Mock
    private MyFactory myFactory;
    
    private MyMapper myMapper;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // ... myFactory stubs ...
        
        myMapper = new MyMapperImpl(myFactory);
    }
    
    // ... tests ...
}
```

Comment: You can also use setter injection