# How can I use spring injection, A repository class in a mapstruct mapper?

Tags: java, spring, mapping, mapstruct, mapper

```
@Data
public class FilesDTO {

    private int issue;
    private String uniqueStr;
    private StorageDomain xml;
    private StorageDomain pdf;
    private StorageDomain stop;
}
@Data
public class BackHalfDomain {
    private int articleId;
    private String uniqueStrr;
    private long xmlContentId;
    private long pdfContentId;
    private long stopId;
    private int issueNumber;
}
```

Using a repository class I have to fetch a `StorageDomain` object from the ID in `BackHalfDomain`. So I have to map `StorageDomain` object with respective fields.
like `StorgeDomain sd = repo.findById(id).get();` and set this `sd` object in `FilesDTO`'s xml field and so on.
This is my mapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface FilesDTOMapper {

    public static final FilesDTOMapper fileDTOMapper = Mappers.getMapper(FilesDTOMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "issue", source = "domain.issueNumber")
    @Mapping(target = "DOI", source = "domain.doi")
    public FilesDTO map(BackHalfDomain domain);

}
```

I have used `uses` but wasn't successful.
I have used `@Mapping(target="xyz", expression="java(repo.findById(id))")"`
but all I got was `NullPointerException`
Spring injection isin't working.
Can someone have a solution for this? I am just started with `mapstruct`

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807415/mapstruct-how-can-i-inject-a-spring-dependency-in-the-generated-mapper-class ?

Comment: @RUAROThibault Yes I checked that. Still after following that post no result in my favour.

Answer (score 0):

Since mapstruct 1.2 you can use a combination of @AfterMapping and @Context.

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public interface FilesDTOMapper { 

   @Mapping(target = "xyz", ignore = true)
   @Mapping(target = "issue", source = "domain.issueNumber")
   @Mapping(target = "DOI", source = "domain.doi")
   FilesDTO map( BackHalfDomain domain, @Context MyRepo repo);

   @AfterMapping
   default void map( @MappingTarget FilesDTO target, BackHalfDomain domain, @Context MyRepo repo) {
        target.setXYZ(repo.findById(domain.getId()));
   }
 }
```

In 1.1 you would need to transform the mapper to a abstract class

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = org.mapstruct.ReportingPolicy.IGNORE,
        componentModel = "spring",
        uses = {})
public abstract class FilesDTOMapper {

    @Autowired
    protected MyRepo repo;


    @Mapping(target = "issue", source = "domain.issueNumber")
    @Mapping(target = "DOI", source = "domain.doi")
    @Mapping(target="xyz", expression="java(repo.findById(domain.getId())))")
    public FilesDTO map(BackHalfDomain domain);

}
```

Comment: I am using  mapstruct version 1.3.0 But this method too didn't fetch me my result. The fields in `FilesDTO` are still null.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem.  The solution was to use a Decorator as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60217018/359974).  Following your code, the solution would be something like the following.

First, we have to specifiy the Decorator in the Mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
@Primary
@DecoratedWith(FilesDTOMapperDecorator.class)
public interface FilesDTOMapper {
      // basic mapping here
      public FilesDTO map(BackHalfDomain domain);
}
```

Then, implement the Decorator:

```
public abstract class FilesDTOMapperDecorator implements FilesDTOMapper {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("delegate")
    private FilesDTOMapper delegate;

    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository someRepository;

    @Override
    public FilesDTO map(BackHalfDomain domain) {
        // Delegate basic mapping
        FilesDTO filesDTO = delegate.map(domain);

        // Use the repository as needed to set additional mapping
        filesDTO.setSomeValue(repo.findById(id).getSomeValue());

        return filesDTO;
    }
}
```