# Spring Boot @Mapper Bean creation issue : Application Failed to start. Error : Consider defining a bean of Type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I am new to spring, when i try to do the `mvn clean install` of my project this problem appears:

**Error**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

**Description**:

Field userService in com.example.accessingdatamysql.rest.MainController required a bean of type 'com.example.accessingdatamysql.service.UserService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.accessingdatamysql.service.UserService' in your configuration.
```

The problem is that in the `MainController` there is the import of "UserService":

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.rest;





import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.service.UserService;


@RestController
public class MainController {
  @Autowired 
         
private UserService userService;

  @Transactional
  @PostMapping(path="/demo/add")
  public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
      , @RequestParam String email,@RequestParam String surname) 
  {
 

    UserDto n = new UserDto();
    n.setName(name);
    n.setSurname(surname);
    n.setEmail(email);
    userService.create(n);
    return "Saved";
  }



 


  @GetMapping("/demo/first")
  public UserDto one(@RequestParam String name) {
   System.out.print(name);
  return userService.findFirstByName(name); 
  }
}
```

It is probably a trivial thing but I can not bypass the problem, below I insert "UserService" and the MainStart

**UserService.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.service;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.dto.UserDto;

public interface UserService {

    UserDto findFirstByName(String name);
    
    void create(UserDto user);
        
}
```

**UPDATE** :
I insert the UserServiceImpl and the new main and Mapper, with the new error.

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.entity.UserEntity;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.repo.UserRepository;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.util.UserMapper;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    
    @Autowired
      private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    UserMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public UserDto findFirstByName(String name) {
           UserEntity entity = userRepository.findFirstByName(name);
           
        return mapper.toDtoMapper(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void create(UserDto user) {
         UserEntity entity = mapper.toEntityMapper(user);
         
         userRepository.create(entity);
        
    }
 
}
```

**AccessingDataMysqlApplication.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.example.accessingdatamysql",
"com.example.accessingdatamysql.util"})
public class AccessingDataMysqlApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataMysqlApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

**UserMapper.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.util;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.entity.UserEntity;


@Mapper (componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

    UserEntity toEntityMapper (UserDto user);
    
    UserDto toDtoMapper (UserEntity userEntity);
}
```

**New Error**:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field mapper in com.example.accessingdatamysql.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.accessingdatamysql.util.UserMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.accessingdatamysql.util.UserMapper' in your configuration.
```

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>accessingdatamysql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            </properties>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotate your UserService class implementation [like `UserServiceImpl.java`] with `@Service` or `@Component`. Also make sure this class is located in a sub-package.

This is your main class package :  `com.example.accessingdatamysql`
Your UserService class and all other classes should be kept in a package like : `com.example.accessingdatamysql.xxxxxx`. Ensure this strategy is followed.

Plus remove the unnecessary annotations on your main class. The **@SpringBootApplication** annotation is equivalent to using the below 3 :
:

1. @Configuration,
2. @EnableAutoConfiguration and
3. @ComponentScan with attributes.

This will be enough :

```
@SpringBootApplication (scanBasePackages = "com.example.accessingdatamysql")
```

And do not keep a gap when you autowire any bean injection. This does not cause any harm. But your code should be properly organized and indentation done.

Also replace below :

```
 @Autowired 
         
private UserService userService;
```

With this :

```
 @Autowired          
 private UserService userService;
```

**UPDATE-1**

Do a maven clean install after you fix your spring boot configurations.

**mvn clean install**

**UPDATE-2**

Your bean for Mapper does not fully qualify for a spring bean. You need to compile your project with the below plugin (see the 2nd plugin I have used).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <compilerArg>
                        -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                    </compilerArg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you need to fix your **UserDto.java** as below (change the type of timestamp variable else Mapper will fail):

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;




private Timestamp timestamp;

public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

Your main class should only have this : `@SpringBootApplication (scanBasePackages = "com.example.accessingdatamysql")` and no other annotation.

Then save your project. And Then run : **mvn clean install -X**

Make your package structure like this :

[image: Package-Structure]

And your classes arranged in the below way :

[image: Classes-in-packages]

Comment: Hi Som! I loaded the UserServiceImpl class, Mapper and the new Main, but now I have a similar mapper problem even though the Autowireds seem to me to be placed correctly

Comment: Do a maven clean install, this will solve your problem. Ex : `mvn clean install`

Comment: Can you paste the exact error that you got for your @Mapper

Comment: I put the error in the UPDATE, if you mean what maven returns me instead, I insert it

Comment: Try keep this constructor in your Mapper class. 

`public UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( UserMapper .class );` I think your configurations are correct. A maven clean build should resolve your issue. Also check if you are using any Implementation for your Mapper or you are simply using the default configuration.

Comment: Tried, nothing changes

Comment: If you are using maven , can u please tell me which spring boot version u are using. Also the dependency in the pom.xml. Ans also please tell which IDE u are using. Eclipse/IntelliJ etc .... And beside that try the following : `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN)`

Comment: Hi Som, if it's more convenient, I can send you the project directly on Skype or Teams. otherwise I insert the POM in the update. I am using Sprin-boot-Suite

Comment: For example, if I insert AccessingDataMysql.java inside the accessingdatamysql folder it doesn't give problems, but it doesn't recognize the get the post

Comment: skype id : somnath.ch1@hotmail.com

Comment: @Jacket : bro ur problem is resolved. Check the UPDATE-2 in my answer. If you face any issue let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a bean to let the Spring use them such as DI(Dependency Injection) `@Autowired` in this case.

There are various ways to define the beans but in your case using `@Service` annotation on the service class so that Spring can find it during the initialization.

And you don't need to declare `@ComponentScan` annotation the `@SpringbootApplication` will handle everything.

As @Som said, you need to implement your `Userservice` class  since it is interface and there is no implemented class yet.

Try to remove `@ComponentScan` annotation and implement `UserService` interface as follow

```java
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    // the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Hi ! I loaded the UserServiceImpl class, Mapper and the new Main, but now I have a similar mapper problem even though the Autowireds seem to me to be placed correctly

Comment: Tried, nothing changes

Comment: @Jacket Sorry my last comment was wrong. Check out the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38843852/9517076)