# Unable to autowire the MapStruct mapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest, mapstruct

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-partial-update) about the partial update. As instructed, I created mapper interface with proper annotations.

Here's the mapper

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserEntityMapper {
  
  @Mapping(source = "password", target = "password")
  @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
  void updatePasswordFromDTO(PasswordResetRequest dto, @MappingTarget User entity);
}
```

As per the tutorial, `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")` generates mapper as a Spring bean that can be retrieved via `@Autowired`.

But when I tried to do same in my service layer `class`,

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class AccountServiceImpl implements IAccountService {
  ...
  @Autowired
  private UserEntityMapper userMapper;
  ...
}
```

I get this error, my application failed to start.

```java
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userMapper in com.application.services.AccountServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.application.mappers.UserEntityMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.application.mappers.UserEntityMapper' in your configuration.
```

And at last, here's `pom.xml` of my project.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>authentication-template</name>
    <description>Description</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I also tried these different solution, but same result.

1. [Answer By @Som](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183305)
2. [Answer by @Gunnar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38843852)

### Edit 1

Here's `@SpringBootApplication` file.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources(value = {
  @PropertySource("classpath:mail.properties"),
  @PropertySource("classpath:messages.properties"),
  @PropertySource("classpath:security.properties")
})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

### Edit 2

Package structure of the project

[image: Package structure of the project]

Please help, Thank you :)

Comment: You didn't show any configuration, such as your `@SpringBootApplication` class.

Comment: Hey @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, I added `@SpringBootApplication` file. Please take a look.

Comment: Is the package where you stuck your mapper one of the ones being picked up by the component scan?

Comment: Hi @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, yes the package where mapper interface is stuck is being picked up by component scan.
Please take a look at the **package structure** image

Comment: Please edit your SBA file to include its package statement.

Comment: Could you please explain how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, I'm too late. Apologies for the delay in responding to the question. Let's dive into configuring MapStruct.

The actual issue was with **configuration**. I follow the following steps to successfully configure **MapStruct** with **Spring Boot**.

1. First add `mapstruct` dependency in `pom.xml`.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
       <optional>true</optional>
       <scope>provided</scope> <!-- Required -->
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
       <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   > **Note:** Make sure `<scope>provided</scope>` is set for `lombok`. Without that `@Builder` was not working for me.
2. Since `mapstruct` requires annotation processing, so we need to add the plugin into our `pom.xml`.

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.11.0</version>
       <configuration>
           <annotationProcessorPaths>
               <path>
                   <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                   <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                   <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
               </path>
               <path>
                   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                   <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                   <version>0.2.0</version>
               </path>
               <path>
                   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                   <version>1.18.30</version>
               </path>
           </annotationProcessorPaths>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

   > **Note:** `lombok-mapstruct-binding` is required for `Lombok` and `Mapstruct`, to allow them to cooperate.
3. Make sure annotation processing is enable in you IDE. You can check these links for [IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44457133) and [Eclipse/STS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44674739)
4. Once done, you can create `mapper interface`.

   ```
   import static org.mapstruct.MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING;

   @Mapper(componentModel = SPRING)
   public interface UserMapper {
     UserModel dtoToModel(UserDTO userDto);
   }
   ```
5. Then the `mapper` can be easily `@Autowired`.

   ```
   @Service
   public class UserService {

       private final UserMapper userMapper;

       @Autowired
       public UserService(UserMapper userMapper) {
           this.userMapper= userMapper;
       }

       // Business logic
   }
   ```

**I hope this will help. Thanks and Regards.**

Answer (score 3):

If the pom.xml you provided is the latest version, I think you are missing the step, that actually generates the MapStruct mappers from your definitions. You need to define it as part of the build setup as stated here https://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/

You need to add that part to the build - plugins section

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                <target>1.8</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <!-- other annotation processors -->
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Also check your target/generated folders if the mappers are successfully generated

**EDIT:**

after running the build, please verify, that your maven build output folder **target/generated-sources** actually contains some generated mappers for MapStruct. Also observe your maven build log output for hints, that MapStruct mappers are generated.

IF no mappers are generated, something in your build setup is fishy and we'd need a closer look into your log output.

But IF mappers are generated, you should check, that that have the @Component annotation of spring AND that they are in a package, that is on Springs scan-path for beans.

Comment: Hey @Marius, thanks for looking into my issue. I added that part in `plugins` section of `pom.xml` but still getting the same error :(

Comment: This is not _usually_ required with modern Java, as the SPI system finds annotation processors.

Answer (score 2):

I have the dependency like below, all the things are Ok.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And in part of plugins.

```xml
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                      <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                      </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Hey @Faramarz, thanks for looking into my issue. I added that part in `plugins` section of `pom.xml` but still getting the same error :(

Comment: @anshuman If you are using lombok you also need to add `lombok` and `lombok-mapstruct-binding` in the `annotationProcessorPaths` as well. In addition to that you also need to validate that the generated source are created. Check whether it works only with Maven as well

Comment: worked for me 2024 jan

Answer (score 2):

Added to plugins:

```
 <compilerArgs>
      <compilerArg>
             -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
      </compilerArg>
 </compilerArgs>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work follow these steps, also I was using **lombok & mapstruct** together with maven

Step 1: Add lombok & mapstruct dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Step 2: Since both mapstruct & lombok are based on annotation processing. Add config in maven build plugin section, you don't need this step if using IntelliJ IDEA, by enabling annotation processiong in IDE settings.

```
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass></mainClass> <!-- FQN of class with main method
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Step 3: Mapper class should have be annotated with @Mapper annotation

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@Service
public interface PersonMapper {
     // add appropriate mapper methods
}
```

Step 3: Update maven project & run

> mvn clean install

Run the application. Inside target folder there will be PersonMapperImpl.java generated by mapstruct.

Answer (score 0):

There are several suggestions you can investigate. First, check if there is @Component in the class generated by mvn.

- If so, check if your application is configured to scan that package.
- If no, try to read [the MapStruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#retrieving-mapper).

Comment: I do read the MapStruct docs. As per the docs `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")` **generates mapper as a Spring bean that can be retrieved via `@Autowired`.**

Comment: @anshuman As Giang suggested, please look in`target/generated-sources` to see if you have the expected Java files.