# Mapstruct value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, properties, mapstruct, mapper

Is it possible to set a value from a field from the *application.properties* file?

I am looking for something like

```
    @Mapping(target="version", expression="${application.version}")
    StateDto stateToStateDto(State state);
```

where `application.version=v1` is from the *application.properties* file.

Answer (score 6):

Consider a "util service" like:

```java
@Service
public class PropertyService {

  @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value("${application.version}")
  private String appVersion;

  // accessors, more properties/stuff..
}
```

Then you can define your Mapping like:

```java
@Mapper(// ..., ...
   componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class StateMapper {

  @Autowired
  protected PropertyService myService;

  @org.mapstruct.Mapping(target="version", expression="java(myService.getAppVersion())")
  public abstract StateDto stateToStateDto(State state);
  // ...
}
```

See also:

- [Mapstruct - How can I inject a spring dependency in the Generated Mapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38807415/592355)
- [Mapstruct Expressions](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions)

---

[My minimal solution @github](https://github.com/xerx593/soq69942709)

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: `myService` appears to be `null` when I run the code

Comment: I fixed some bugs in my post (private  -> protected, abstract method), and added a (working!;) sample to github! :-)

Comment: It is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 2):

As far as my knowledge goes, this is **not** possible. Mapstruct analyses the `@Mapping` annotation in compile time. And the annotation parameters require constants. So getting them from a file would not be possible.

You can always implement something in `MapStruct` that fulfills your needs. But I would go with a simple self-implemented mapper where you take the value from your `version` field in runtime from the environment.

EDIT:

This is possible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75732083/7954021).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple. You just use `abstract class` instead of `interface`, then you can use directly the `@Value` annotation.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class StateMapper {
    @Value("${application.version}")
    protected String applicationVersion;

    @Mapping(target = "version", expression = "java(this.applicationVersion)")
    public abstract StateDto map(State state);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible through MapStruct. However, a feature could be raised that would support some custom expression language that would use Spring `@Value` and inject that.

e.g.

```
@Mapping(target="version", expression="springValue(${application.version})")
StateDto stateToStateDto(State state);
```

and then MapStruct will generate something like:

```
@Component
public class StateMapperImpl {

    @Value("${application.version}")
    private String version;


    // ...
}
```

Comment: Downvoted for the statment "This is not possible through MapStruct", because this **is** possible, see my answer.